# Using DENSE_RANK in Obiee

Tags: obiee, dense-rank

someone can explain to me how i apply **DENSE_RANK** on obiee?
Obiee only have the **RANK** function, i tried with **EVALUATE** function but doesn´t work.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

How does it "not work"?!

Because it does and your "doesn't work" is probably due to a syntax error.

EVALUATE(‘DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY %2 ORDER BY %1)’AS INTEGER,”Org”.”Market”, ”Measures”.”Revenue”)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, i needed to change a configuration on the server, do you know of any function that plays the same role as dense_rank?
Thank you

Comment: Do you mean you had to activate EVALUATE support in the NQSConfig.ini first? That wouldn't surprise me. But what do you mean with "same role as dense_rank"? dense_rank is dense_rank. Is the above formula not what you need?

Comment: I have a "Group Number" with numbers that are randomly assigned, within this Group I have "departments", I want to give sequential numbers (1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ...) to the groups and associate only the group number in all departments in that group, the rank function jumps numbers depending on which departments we have, can you understand? I would like to know if it is possible to execute the dense_rank function in OBIEE12c in another way (for example mathematically), this is because to execute the dense_rank I need to add configs on the server and I don't have access to it. Thanks.